# Geany - how to disable mark option in find function?

Tags: 20.04, find, geany, markdown

I pressed *mark* but now I have no idea how to disable it. And I can not google this. Just closing the window doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the search menu, select *More*, then *Mark All*. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.